# Matlab arrays, vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector

I have a silly question which I cannot seem to answer at the moment (too tired maybe). How do I store a variable in an array? Here is my bit of code:

```
for u0=xDesired(1):0.01:xDesired(2),
     [T,Y] = ode23(@RateDE,[T],[Yminitial Yinitial],[],[u0 g k]);
    %#Peaks
    P1 = findpeaks(T,Y(:,1),0,-1,5,5); %Peaks for Alpha(T)
    P2 = findpeaks(T,Y(:,2),0,-1,5,5);  %Peaks for Tetha(T)
    W = size(P2(:,2)); %Counts the number of peaks in Tetha(T)
    W1 = size(P1(:,2)); %Counts the number of peaks in Alpha(T)
    PAl = P1(W1-10:end,2); %Extracts the last11 elements in Alpha(T)
    PBe = P2(W-10:end,2); %Extracts the last 11 elements in Tetha(T)
    %#Valleys 
    v1 = findvalleys(T,Y(:,1),0,-1,5,5);  %Valleys for Alpha(T)
    v2 = findvalleys(T,Y(:,2),0,-1,5,5); %Valleys for Tetha(T)
    Z = size(v1(:,2)); %Counts the number of valleys in Alpha(T)
    Z1 = size(v2(:,2)); %Counts the number of valleys in Tetha(T) 
    VAl = v1(Z-10:end,2); %Extracts the last 11 elements in Alpha(T)
    VBe = v2(Z1-10:end,2); %Extracts the last 11 elements in Tetha(T)
    **%#Period
    Periodalpha = mean(abs(PAl - VAl));
    Periodbetha = mean(abs(PBe - VBe));
    %#Amplitudes
    Ampalpha = mean(P1(W1-10:end,3));
    Ampbetha = mean(P2(W1-10:end,3));
    %display(u0)
    %display(Periodalpha) 
    %display(Ampalpha)
 end

 %plot(u0, Periodalpha); 
 %plot(u0, Ampalpha);
```

The variables I want to store in an array are "Periodalpha/betha and Ampalpha/betha" so that I could plot u0 vs Periodalpha then betha etc ..

However, on the workspace I don't get an array for those variables, I only get the last value of it.

Any hint/help would be much appreciated ! Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets take a look at the variable Periodalpha; have you checked size(Periodalpha)?  It is calculated as:

```
Periodalpha = mean(abs(PAl - VAl));
```

but before that you have:

```
PAl = P1(W1-10:end,2); %Extracts the last11 elements in Alpha(T)
```

and

```
VAl = v1(Z-10:end,2); %Extracts the last 11 elements in Alpha(T)
```

I can't tell with 100% certainty but it appears that you take the difference of two 11 element vectors, then calc the mean, which returns a single scalar value.  So you are doing something like this:

```
mean(abs(rand(1,11) - rand(1,11)))

ans =

    0.3040
```

Which might explain why you are seeing single value for the variable, Periodalpha.

At least I think that is what is happening.

**EDIT**: Looking again at your code I see that you are iterating over u0 values and then at each value, calculating Periodalpha (among other things). But each time through the loop you are not saving any of the previous values, i.e., the value for u0 and Periodalpha are reset each time.

So just store the u0 and Periodalpha values in a separate array.  First, initialize a couple of tracking arrays like this (outside your u0 loop):

```
u0Track = [];
PeriodalphaTrack = [];
```

and then inside your loop append the new values to these tracking arrays:

```
for u0 =
...

    u0Track = [u0Track u0];
    PeriodalphaTrack = [PeriodalphaTrack Periodalpha];
end
```

When your loop is done you can then plot(u0Track, PeriodalphaTrack).

Make sense?

Comment: That's right, but now I was wondering how could store that scalar back into an array so that I could plot against u0.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but I would think that you would be plotting more than a single (x,y) point?  Its ok if your not, I'm just trying to understand what you have here.

Comment: On each itteration of u0, I would get a new value of periodalpha, periodbetha, ampalpha and ampbetha. I would then plot u0 against periodalpha, u0 vs periodbetha etc ... The problem I have here is that, as you mentionned previously I get a scalar and not an array which I could plot.

Comment: Ok I think I see what might be happening, I'll provide an edit to my answer, let me know if that explains it.

Comment: Alright, now I see! I was trying to use this technique[link]http://www.ehow.com/how_8686535_save-variables-array-matlab.html) with no success. Thank you for the help.

Comment: As you are using a `for` loop the amount of steps is known in advance. Hence it is good practice to initialize the tracking variables directly at their final size to prevent growing these variables in every step. Of course you would need a counting variable to know in which step you are and where to store the values.